# image in a HTTP server and HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, sockets, http

I'm trying to create an HTTP server with python.

All is working exept the image does not load in Google chrome or Microsoft Edge using localhost:{port}.

[image: What we can see on browsers]

There is the code :

```py
import socket
import time

http_head = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
http_head += "Date:"+ time.asctime() +"GMT\r\n"
http_head += "Expires: -1\r\n"
http_head += "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\n"
http_head += "Content-Type: text/html;"
http_head += "charset=utf-8\r\n"
http_head += "\r\n"
data = "<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'/></head>"
data += "<body><h1>In321 is the best course ! (doubt) </h1>"
data += "\r\n"
data += "<img src=\"C:\\Users\\aliel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\TP2_In321\\crying_cat_with_thumb_up.jpg\" alt=\"A crying cat with thumb up\">"
data += "</body></html>\r\n"
data += "\r\n"
http_response = http_head.encode("ascii") + data.encode("utf-8")

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 55000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))  # Demande à l’OS d’associer la socket à une ip/port

s.listen(1)   # transforme la socket en socket de connexion
print(" Waiting client… ")


scom, caddr = s.accept()
print("client connected with address : ", caddr)
data = scom.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print("received data:", data.decode('utf-8'))
scom.send(http_response)

s.close()
scom.close()
```

Comment: Instead of using sockets to create an HTTP server, you can also try using the [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) module which is part of the python standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is since you're using a string, the browser after loading the HTML content tries to load the image but then notices that you're trying to read a local file and hence blocks the request. (If you right click the image and click copy image address you can see it says `"about:blank#blocked"`). The way you can circumvent this is either by Creating an HTML file or embedding the image as bytes in the string itself.
You can do that as follows

```
import base64
with open(path,"rb") as i:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(i.read()).decode( 'utf-8' )
```

and adding the following to your image source (where `path` is the path to your image)

```
data += f'<img src="data:image/png;base64, {encoded_string}">'
```

Comment: So I added `import base64
with open("C:\\Users\\aliel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\TP2_In321\\crying_cat_with_thumb_up.jpg","rb") as i:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(i.read())` to my code, then I replaced `src=\"C:\\Users\\aliel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\TP2_In321\\crying_cat_with_thumb_up.jpg\"` by `src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64;+encoded_string\"` But nothing changed.

Comment: And instead of /a, I write the path ?

Comment: Yes. Here, I'll fix it. Try using this instead: with open(path,"rb") as i:     encoded_string = base64.b64encode(i.read()).decode( 'utf-8' ) and add data += f'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {encoded_string}">'